# Set-Cookie in Nginx and check

Tags: nginx, cookies, conditional-statements

I'm trying to set cookie (there is no problem setting cookie) and checking is it exist or not, If its not exist i want to return 401. But it doesn't work. Written code is between server brackets.

```
 add_header Set-Cookie "botcheck=1033;Domain=xxx.com;Path=/;Max-Age=31536000";

    if ($cookie_botcheck != "1033") {
            return 401;
            break;
    }
```

Comment: When you add the header, I assume the cookie will apply from the next request and not current request. The current request didn't still send that cookie.

Comment: So how can i set-cookie at first request?

Comment: I doubt it can work at nginx level. You would need Nginx + Lua or use something on server side for this